# the row size is 8135 which is greater than maximum allowed size (8126)

Tags: mysql, innodb

Currently we are using MySQL 5.6 and now upgrading to MySQL8. We have taken the db dump in MySQL5.6 and then reinstalled MySQL8, and now restoring the db dump. When we are doing it, we are facing the issue of row size for some tables: 
    the row size is 8135 which is greater than maximum allowed size (8126)

Compared couple of properties between MySQL5.6 and MySQL8, found that MySQL 8 has these bigger properties
innodb_log_file_size
innodb_log_buffer_size
max_allowed_packet

Since it is working fine on MySQL5.6, I was hoping that it should work fine with MySQL8 also. Please let me know what changes can be done here, without impacting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding following line in your MySQL configuration file.

```
innodb_strict_mode = OFF
```

Comment: Please do such only for the duration of the restore.

Answer (score 1):

```
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

If contain, remove it from your sql.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to 5.6 and shrink some of your varchar/text columns.  And/or use vertical partitioning.  Having a big 'row size' is doing something 'wrong'.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further critique.